# Compare and delete lines based on first x character match (between two files)

Tags: python, windows, list, text, compare

I have two text files in the CWD, a.txt, and b.txt. **From a.txt**, I would like to **delete all lines whose first 5 characters are NOT present in b.txt** as any lines' first 5 characters.  (Or, saying otherwise, keep only those lines in a.txt, whose first 5 characters is present in b.txt as any lines' first 5 characters.) Content after the 5th character to the end of the line is irrelevant.

For example:
**a.txt**

```
abcde000
0123456xxx
xyzxyzxyz
kkkkkkkkkkk
```

**b.txt**

```
012345aabbcc
kkkkkkkhhkkvv
nnnnnnnnnnn
```

**result** (lines in a.txt whose 1-5 character is present in b.txt):

```
0123456xxx
kkkkkkkkkkk
```

**Script in progress** (I am stuck how to search for exact matches withing the first 5 characters):

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('b.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

        file1[0][4]
        file1[0][4]

same.discard('\n')

with open('same_start.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
with open('a.txt') as f1, open('b.txt') as f2:

    lines1 = f1.readlines()
    lines2 = f2.readlines()

    result = []

    for line1 in lines1:
        for line2 in lines2:
            if len(line1.strip()) >= 5 and line1[:5] == line2[:5]:  
                result.append(line1)


with open('a.txt', 'w') as f1:
    f1.writelines(result)
```

---

Note that Python's slices are very insidious since `s[:100]` from a string of length less than 101 is the same string. Therefore you should check - whether each line contains a sufficient number of characters. In the method above, this is implemented through the condition `len(line1.strip()) >= 5`, which guarantees that the provided method will eliminate lines of length less than 5 as well as long lines of spaces.

For example:

```
a.txt
---------------
abcde000
0123456xxx
xyzxyzxyz
kkkkkkkkkkk

1
          # <== 10 spaces here
2
3
```

```
b.txt
---------------
012345aabbcc
kkkkkkkhhkkvv
nnnnnnnnnnn
            # <== 12 spaces here

1
2
3
```

```
result (a.txt)
---------------
0123456xxx
kkkkkkkkkkk
```

Answer (score 1):

In two line solution:

```
b_file=[line.strip() for line in open('b.txt','r')]
a_file=[j for line in open('a.txt','r') for j in b_file if line[:5] in j ]
```

Then you can write output of a_file to a.txt:

```
with open('a.txt','w') as f:
    for item in a_file:
        f.write(item + '\n')
```

> Detailed solution:

```
compare=[]
with open('b.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        compare.append(line.strip())
new=[]
with open('a.txt') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        for j in compare:
            if line[:5] in j:
                new.append(j)


with open('a.txt','w') as f3:
    for j in new:
        f3.write(j+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the first 5 characters of every line in file2 into a list and then check if any line of file a's first 5 character is present in that list!

```
>>> with open('c.txt','w') as out:
...     with open('a.txt','r') as inp1, open('b.txt','r') as inp2:
...             infile2_content=[line[:5] for line in inp2.readlines()]
...             [out.write(line) for line in inp1 if line[:5] in infile2_content]
...
[None, None]
>>>
>>> with open('c.txt','r') as f:
...     print f.read().splitlines()
...
['0123456xxx', 'kkkkkkkkkkk']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as file1:
    a_lines = file1.readlines()
    with open('b.txt', 'r') as file2:
        short_b = [b[:5] for b in file2.readlines()]
        keepers = [a.strip() for a in a_lines if a[:5] in short_b]

keepers
['0123456xxx', 'kkkkkkkkkkk']
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try with this code

```
list2=['pankajsdhasjfdvajshf','mithsfggasjfasjhf']
list1=['pankajddsdsdf','mithilieshdsfsfsfsdf']

for i in range (0,len(list1)):
    for j in range (0,len(list2)):
        if list1[i][0:6] in list2[j][0:6]:
            print 'true'
            print list1[i]
        else:
            print 'fail'
```